# A workaround this kubernetes error: The Ingress "generated-ingress" is invalid: metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 characters

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, haproxy-ingress

I'm trying to replicate what we have set up in our bare-metal infrastructure using AWS. I'm admittedly not well-versed with K8S, but a colleague of mine had started to use it in AWS so I've been piggybacking on some of the work he's done. He's been able to answer most of my questions, but this one seems to have us a little stumped.

In our bare-metal setup, there are about 20k unique sites with individual SSL certificates. In doing a small scale test with a few sites and certs, it works. However, at full scale, it does not.

I was able to script importing the certificates into K8S and create a voyager ingress configuration yaml file from it, but when I try to apply it, I get the following error message:

```
bash-5.0# kubectl apply -f generated-ingress.yaml
The Ingress "generated-ingress" is invalid: metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 characters
```

It seems that the ingress configuration is too large.

The generated ingress looks something like this:

```
---
apiVersion: voyager.appscode.com/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: generated-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: ssl-cert-eample-domain.com
      hosts:
        - example-domain.com
    # Repeated for each domain using SSL
  rules:
    - host: '*'
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: the-backend
            servicePort: '80'
    - host: example-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: the-backend
            servicePort: '80'
            headerRules:
            - X-HTTPS YES 
    # Repeated for each domain using SSL
```

FYI the `X-HTTPS` header is needed for our backend to generate absolute urls correctly using `https` instead of `http`. It would be nice if this could be specified for all SSL connections instead of having to specify it for each individual domain, making the configuration more lean.

In any case, is there a way to increase the limit for the configuration? Or is there a better way to configure the ingress for numerous SSL certificates?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are getting bitten by `kubectl` trying to record the previous state of affairs in an `{"metadata":{"annotation":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration": "GINORMOUS string"}}}` [as described here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#how-to-create-objects). It's not the `Ingress` itself that is causing you problems.

In your case, because the input object is so big, I believe you will have to use [`kubectl replace`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#replace) instead of `apply`, since (a) you appear to have the whole declaration in-hand anyway (b) I don't think `kubectl replace` tries to capture that annotation unless one explicitly provides `--save-config=true` to `replace`

---

Separate from your question, if you are not already aware, one need not declare **every single `Ingress`** in one resource -- it is much, much, much, much, much easier to manage and reason about `Ingress` resources when they are distinct

So your config of:

```
apiVersion: voyager.appscode.com/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: generated-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: ssl-cert-eample-domain.com
      hosts:
        - example-domain.com
    # Repeated for each domain using SSL
  rules:
    - host: '*'
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: the-backend
            servicePort: '80'
    - host: example-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: the-backend
            servicePort: '80'
            headerRules:
            - X-HTTPS YES
```

would become:

```
apiVersion: voyager.appscode.com/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: star-domain
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - host: '*'
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: the-backend
            servicePort: '80'
```

and then repeat this structure for every one of the domains:

```
apiVersion: voyager.appscode.com/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-domain
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: ssl-cert-example-domain.com
      hosts:
        - example-domain.com
  rules:
    - host: example-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: the-backend
            servicePort: '80'
            headerRules:
            - X-HTTPS YES
```

*it's also redundantly redundant to put `ingress` in the `metadata: name:` of an `Ingress` resource, as when one is typing its name you will need to say `kubectl describe ingress/generated-ingress`*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do agree that breaking it up is easier to reason about and organize. I didn't know it could be set up that way.

I tried to load the ingress by splitting it up into separate files and loading the directory. I gave each ingress the same name because I did not want to have multiple ingresses created - they should all still be part of the same ingress, but what I found was that only the last file processed seemed to get applied, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: That's actually not true, you _do_ want multiple `Ingress`es created, so you can reason about them. Perhaps you meant that you don't want multiple ingress _controllers_ created, which is not a thing you are at risk of by splitting apart the `rules:` like I demonstrated. You will want to give each `Ingress` resource a name that tells your colleagues what kind of rules can be found in the `Ingress` resource so they don't have to guess

Comment: I think you're right. I used the wrong terminology.

That said, I have to be careful here because there are thousands of sites so I don't want to mistakenly create a bunch of ingress controllers.

I guess I'll grab just a few, give them unique names, and see what happens.

Comment: Ok I tried it with a handful of them. This will not work well for my situation. Having a separate ingress creates separate hostnames for each ingress which is not desirable. It's looking more and more like I'll just need to create a custom ingress to cover our needs.

Comment: You're right about the wrong terminology, and it's impossible to help you until you use the right words, because what you are describing is not the way `Ingress` works. I'll point out you still haven't accepted my answer that solved your problem with the "annotation too long" error. The part below the line was just an observation that is separate from your question, and if it your workflow needs one huge file, then continue editing one huge file

Comment: While the answer you gave does get around the "annotation too long" error, it doesn't fully resolve the issue. My original question about how to get around or increase the configuration limits still stands as I get the error message `Error from server: error when creating "generated-ingress.yaml": rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = trying to send message larger than max (3111483 vs. 2097152)` when it tries to create it. Also, replace tears the original ingress down, which isn't desirable in my use case. I have learned quite a bit from our conversation though, so thank you.

Comment: Then I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree about whether I solved your stated problem, which then allowed you to discover a _new_ problem

Comment: kubectl replace -f <file.yaml> worked for me.